# What is Wrong with My Reverse Lookup PTR Record

Tags: windows-server-2016, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I can't figure out why my PTR record does not work on my new server. This configuration worked on my old server and I already confirmed with my host that they added a record on their end so that 72.164.185.in-addr.arpa points to serer.copblaster.com but whenever I do a rDNS check of IP address 185.164.72.225 on MxToolBox or anything else it says no PTR record found.

As my screenshot clearly shows I have a basic reverse lookup zone with PTR record setup properly.

[image]

UPDATE: Does this info help at all?

### C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup -debug -d2 -type=PTR 185.164.72.225

SendRequest(), len 40
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
```

### ------------

Got answer (40 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
```

---

Server:  UnKnown
Address:  127.0.0.1

---

SendRequest(), len 45
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    225.72.164.185.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
```

### ------------

Got answer (105 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    225.72.164.185.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
->  185.in-addr.arpa
    type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 48
    ttl = 1761 (29 mins 21 secs)
    primary name server = pri.authdns.ripe.net
    responsible mail addr = dns.ripe.net
    serial  = 1576110715
    refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
    retry   = 600 (10 mins)
    expire  = 864000 (10 days)
    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)
```

---

*** UnKnown can't find 225.72.164.185.in-addr.arpa.: Non-existent domain

Answer (score 1):

Reverse DNS records on the public DNS need to be added by your ISP that owns the IP address. PTR records added to your windows DNS server are typically not accessible on the public internet. Windows DNS is not typically your authoritative DNS server for your domain or PTR records. Windows DNS is usually used to host internal (to your LAN) DNS records and will either use root hints or forwarders to resolve external domains.

Please contact your ISP to update PTR records.

Comment: I did contact my ISP and they say they added a rDNS entry and even showed me a screenshot of them selecting my IP address from a dropdown list labeled "range" next to a textbox that says "72.164.185.in-addr.arpa server.copblaster.com" and a button that says "save". The name of the image file starts with "Smart Select" I don't know if that is relevant at all.